# only 30GB of my 60GB is available

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

brand new install of Ubuntu 20.04, using ESXI I allocated 60GB for the drive.  However `df -h` shows significantly less space available.

```
ubuntu@test:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               951M     0  951M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              199M  1.2M  198M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   29G  4.1G   24G  15% /
tmpfs                              994M     0  994M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              994M     0  994M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  103M  806M  12% /boot
/dev/loop0                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2                          72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16099
tmpfs                              199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/1000
```

and

```
ubuntu@test:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop1                       7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                       7:2    0 71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
sda                         8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   59G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 29.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I use the default recommendations during installation, not sure if that was my problem?

[image]

It looks like it's only allocating 50% of the disk space available?  Is this normal for a default installation?  I don't want to have to remember to adjust this each time I setup a new VM. Plus it seems that machines with less than 20GB of disk space don't seem to have this issue.  So I'm at a loss of what is actually happening, and how to address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults on the Subiquity server installer use only 50% of the LVM volume group as you can see by the "29.498G" in your Size for `ubuntu-lv`. So, unless you adjust that at install time, you have to change the sizes post-install.

You can extend that while running the system without issue by doing the following to resize the LV after the install:

```
sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

... and then resize the filesystem to fit the new space:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Comment: should it be `sudo lvresize -l ....'  ?

Comment: Correct, with a capital L according to Ubuntu 20.04's usage guidelines for `lvresize`.  I posted this late last night and forgot to include the argument sorry!

Comment: no worries, I was able to figure it out pretty easily with what you had, so you saved me a lot of headache and searching!